# Dataframe not getting ordered by column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary as below:

```
entity_dict=
{u'bam': 1.0,
 u'ham': 1.0,
 u'jam': 0.82390874094431876,
 u'kam': 1.0,
 u'lam': 1.0,
 u'mam': 0.82390874094431876,
 u'pam': 1.0,
 u'ram': 1.0,
 u'sam': 0.82390874094431876,
 u'tam': 1.0}
```

I am trying to convert it into dataframe, I write the below code and get the following result:

```
entity_df = DataFrame.from_dict(entity_dict, orient='index').T 

   lam  ham     sam     ram  kam     jam      tam  bam   mam      pam
0    1    1    0.823909    1    1  0.823909    1    1  0.823909    1
```

The problem is the dataframe is not in the same order as the dictionary:
(bam, which should be the first element shifts to the end)

Therefore I write the following code to sort it by columns:

```
entity_df.reindex_axis(sorted(entity_df.columns), axis=1)
```

## Problem:

The problem I face is a bit weird. when I run both the above command individually one after another in the python console, the dataframe I get is sorted. However, when I execute them together (by writing the code in editor and then run the whole thing) I dont see the dataframe sorted.

Comment: `reindex_axis` does not change the dataframe in place, you have to re-assign it to see the adapted frame: `entity_df = entity_df.reindex_axis(..)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python dictionnary are not ordered. Try using the [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) structure from the python collections module.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

entity_dict = OrderedDict()
entity_dict['bam'] = 1.0
entity_dict['ham'] = 1.0
entity_dict['jam'] = 0.82390874094431876
entity_dict['kam'] = 1.0
entity_dict['lam'] = 1.0
entity_dict['mam'] = 0.82390874094431876
entity_dict['pam'] = 1.0
entity_dict['ram'] = 1.0
entity_dict['sam'] = 0.82390874094431876
entity_dict['tam'] = 1.0

entity_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(entity_dict, orient='index').T 

print(entity_df)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `OrderedDict` to preserve the order of the columns.  Going from your initial code, we can sort the dict by key.

```
#  ... definition for entity_dict
from collections import OrderedDict

sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(entity_dict.items()))
# sorts column alphabetically
entity_df = DataFrame.from_dict(sorted_dict, orient='index').T
```

yields

```
   bam  ham       jam  kam  lam       mam  pam  ram       sam  tam
0    1    1  0.823909    1    1  0.823909    1    1  0.823909    1
```

Alternatively, you can use OrderedDict's tuple syntax when constructing the dict for better performance if you know your keys beforehand.  I have sorted the existing dict by key for brevity here.

Thus equivalently you could defined `sorted_dict` as such

```
from collections import OrderedDict

sorted_dict = OrderedDict([(u'bam', 1.0),
  (u'ham', 1.0),  (u'jam', 0.8239087409443188),
  (u'kam', 1.0),  (u'lam', 1.0),
  (u'mam', 0.8239087409443188),
  (u'pam', 1.0),
  (u'ram', 1.0),
  (u'sam', 0.8239087409443188),
  (u'tam', 1.0)])
```